# How to properly secure post requests with Django RF apis?

Tags: api, security, django-rest-framework

I am currently learning to make DRF APIs for something I am working on. I was wondering how exactly I would secure the API POST requests I send via the client side?

For example, let's say I have a log in form where the user can enter their information, this information needs to be send to (or POST-ed to) my API for verification. I do not want just anyone sending requests to the server and so, I would want to use an API key but since this is being done on a website, anyone could see the API key if they wanted to, and then exploit the server by sending a ton of requests.

My current idea is to use serializes in DRF to check if the API POST request has everything it needs but I am fairly certain this can be easily found by checking what sort of JSON my code sends to the server, so how exactly do I go about securing this such that I can send the information to the bare domain (like http://127.0.0.1:8000) and then have code which can accept that information?

I apologize for any confusion, if it is confusing. Let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating API any one **can send request to server**. same goes for website and webpage. Their is no way you can avoid this. But their are ways to handle possible misuse.

like using CAPTCHA for login form which can be filled by one on the web. though wrong CAPTCHA text can be send by anyone you must check it on server for their correctness. or use google reCAPTCHA like services for outsourcing this task.

API key should be given after login NOT before login. and if it is given after successful login then the key is obtained by legitimate user which can obviously do whatever he is allowed to do on website. their should not be problem in that.

further explanation to the question will lead to details of `denial-of-service` i.e DOS attack. you should consult expert on that field if your application requires to handle DOS attack.